# php multiple class_alias with same class name

Tags: php, namespaces, alias

I am trying to cascade extend a class that is registered via `class_alias`. I am getting a "Cannot redeclare class" warning and am wondering if what I want to do is even possible in PHP.

My aim is to be able to create a "chain" of inheritance. `One\one` is the base class and `Two\one` extends this but also replaces `One\one` as the class that is aliased.

That way any number of classes can extend the main one in a particular namespace without having any knowledge of the other classes in the chain/which other classes have already extended.

one.php

```
namespace One;

class_alias('One\one', 'one');

class one {}
```

two.php

```
namesapce Two;

class_alias('Two\one', 'one');

class one extends \one{}
```

index.php

```
<?php
require('one.php');
require('two.php');

$instance = new \one();
var_dump($instance);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two classes with the same name in the same namespace. You are trying to assign the name `one` twice in the global namespace via the `class_alias` calls.

You are using namespaces and then try to bypass them. What's the need to do that?

Comment: In the HMVC framework I am using I want to ensure that if two modules override the same class they can do without having to know about each other.

Comment: @Uru That is what namespaces are for, but using `class_alias('One\one', 'one');` you "create" a class 'one' in global namespace and you do so twice.

Comment: I see. I guess that what I am trying to achieve is not possible this way then. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Uru Commonly, many PHP frameworks use a factory class to retrieve instantiated objects. Those factory classes often are configurable in some way to declare which classes are actually instantiated when creating an object for model XY. (e.g. in Magento they use XML files, which could get overwritten by extensions, that introduce their own classes) When using `extends` you always have to specify a class name and if you have two classes with the same name you must pass a fully qualified name including namespaces.

Comment: This does not seem to be present functionality in the framework I am using (fuelPHP) but is something I can look at implementing for it.

Comment: I've been struggling with the same stuff for a few days in my own hobby-mvc as well. Trying to mimic how the Magento 1.x folder structure worked but PSR-4. Seems like it's damn near impossible to get right, at least with how PHP's namespaces work - pretty damn useless if you ask me. In combination with global autoloading that can't tell originating namespace without ugly back-trace hacks.. well, if you don't do Dependency Injection you'r not welcome it seems.  I know... lets work around the fact that you can't easily extend classes anymore by introducing Traits instead... Shit's crazy... -.-'